# Confirm text is displayed in webpage with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How can I confirm the text "FIND ME PLEASE" is displayed on a webpage using Java? Please refer to the HTML code below:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
  <tr><td class="fontlargebold" align="center">&nbsp;FIND ME PLEASE&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

The difficulty resides with the HTML code not having attributes such as ID, name, value...etc. I attempted to use xpath (`By.xpath("//*[text()=[contains('FIND ME PLEASE')]]")`) )but I don't think it's correct...

Comment: You're not using the `contains`-function correctly. `contains` needs two arguments, first the content to be searched and second the searchstring. See the [W3C Specifications for contains()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains) for some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath is indeed wrong.

Use

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'FIND ME PLEASE')]")
```

The whole Java code for a method doing your job:

```
public boolean isTextPresent(String text) {
    List<WebElement> foundElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + text + "')]"));
    return foundElements.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked! I really appreciate the quick response. For curiosity sake, why did the path have to be (..., '"+ text + "'), as compared to just (..., text)? Thank you.

Comment: @user2607278 Because in `"//*[contains(text(), text)]"`, `text` is not a variable name, but a string. Tha construct I have there concatenates the XPath expression with the contents of the `text` variable. Search Java String concatenation. No problem for vote, if the answer was helpful, [accept it instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)!

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested whether this text somewhere occurs, and also may contain other markup, go for

```
contains(/html/body, 'FIND ME PLEASE')
```

which will return a boolean value when the content is found.

If you need to return an element instead a boolean value, you can do that, too:

```
/html/body[contains(., 'FIND ME PLEASE')]
```

Comment: While this is true, in the current context (Selenium WebDriver), there's no method that would accept an XPath expression and return a boolean value. Without workarounds, we can only ask for nodes.

Comment: Didn't know that, but only changes the query a little bit, not the concept behind.